# Regular Expression to disallow two consecutive white spaces in the middle of a string

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-user-controls

I need a regex to meet the following requirements:

- Only letters, periods and whitespace are allowed.
- No white space at the beginning and at the end of the string.
- White space in the middle of the string is OK, but not two consecutive white spaces.

Matches:

```
"Hello world."
"Hello World. This is ok."
```

Not Matches:

```
" Hello World. "
"Hello world 123." 
"Hello  world."
```

This worked in my case

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDescription" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="taDescription" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Description." 
                                Text="&nbsp" 
                                ValidationExpression="^(?i)(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})(?!.*[ ]$)[A-Z. ]{8,20}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! First, I think it would be a good idea if you familiarized yourself with the formatting options of the editor  - your question as stated doesn't really reflect your requirements. I'll do this for you this time, so you can see how it works. Second, you haven't really asked a question - what part of the problem are you stuck at? Third, which language are you using? All of these topics are covered in the help page and in the regex FAQ.

Comment: I will definately learn it asap. Thankyou for your help :) @Tim Pietzcker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution in Python, using [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure the whitespace rules are followed:

```
regex = re.compile(
    """^          # Start of string
    (?![ ])       # Assert no space at the start
    (?!.*[ ]{2})  # Assert no two spaces in the middle
    (?!.*[ ]$)    # Assert no space at the end
    [A-Z. ]{8,20} # Match 8-20 ASCII letters, dots or spaces
    $             # End of string""", 
    re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: I am using asp.net user control regular expression validator like this  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDescription" runat="server" ControlToValidate="taDescription" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Description." Text="&nbsp" ValidationExpression="^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})(?!.*[ ]$)[A-Z. ]{8,20}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> . Would you please guide me . Your suggested regex is not working.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad: You didn't make the regex case-insensitive. Add `(?i)` to the very start of the regex.

Comment: Thankyou so much I am done with it. I have done the following changes.  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDescription" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="taDescription" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Description." 
                                Text="&nbsp" 
                                ValidationExpression="^(?i)(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]{2})(?!.*[ ]$)[A-Z. ]{8,20}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>. I am really thankful to you. I have searched alot but finally you gave me the answer. Super :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to check for the length outside of the regular expression, otherwise the expression might get too complicated.

Here's an example snippet in JavaScript:

```
if (str.length < 8 || str.length > 20)
  return false;
if (str.match(/(^\s|\s$|\s\s|[^A-Za-z.\s])/))
  return false;
```

The regular expression checks for a match of any of the forbidden patterns:

- `^\s` a whitespace at the beginning
- `\s$` a whitespace at the end
- `\s\s` two consecutive whitespace characters
- `[^A-Za-z.\s]` a character that is not a letter, period or whitespace

If you will allow only spaces (ASCII 32), not tabs or other whitespace characters, you can replace all `\s` by the literal space character.

Another solution would be a combination of a “positive” expression to check for the permitted characters and length and a “negative” one to rule out the rejected patterns:

```
return str.match(/[A-Za-z. ]){8,20}/) && !str.match(/(^ | $|  )/);
```

**Update**: If you need to put everything into a single expression, I'm afraid you have to leave out the check for consecutive spaces, because this restriction makes the language context-sensitive, hence it cannot be checked by a regular expression. What you can do is to check for a string that begins with a letter, followed by 6 to 18 letters, dots or spaces and ends with a letter:

```
[A-Z][A-Z. ]{6,18}[A-Z]
```

Comment: I am using asp.net Regular Expression Validator . I have changed my code with your suggession but with no Luck. Here is the code.  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revDescription" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="taDescription" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Description." 
                                Text="&nbsp" 
                                ValidationExpression="/(^\s|\s$|\s\s|[^A-Za-z.\s])/"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: I have left the Miimun value and maximun value validation. I will do that by applying Maxlength to textbox. Now I just want not to allow white space in start in end and not to allow two consective white spaces in the middle. Not Match = (Hello  world) = ( Hello World )

Comment: consective white space is the main problem I am done with start white space and end white space like this ^[a-zA-Z][\.\s\a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z\.]$ I just dont want the user to enter conssective spaces.